# Are contents in the Google Drive indexed for searching?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, search-engine

I am applying for graduate admissions this year and one of my publication is in stage in publication with the journal.

I have uploaded the paper on Google Drive and I am planning to provide the link to the paper in my CV using the Google Drive option **"Anyone with the link"**.

Now, my question is, will my document/paper (which is in PDF) get indexed for searching?

If it does, then it might cause plagiarism issues with the process of publication.

Your opinion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Google Docs results to appear in Google Search results?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80882/how-to-get-google-docs-results-to-appear-in-google-search-results)

Comment: No @ahorn. My question is if the PDF files get indexed which are stored in the drive and are enabled to view for anyone with the link.

Comment: If Google Docs don't get indexed, I doubt that PDF files would.

Answer (score 1):

Your document will be indexed if the link is put on a web page, or if you tell the Google Search Console about a website where it's placed. The Google crawlers move amongst websites on the surface web, so if your file is not put on an existing web page on the surface web, it will not be indexed.

Note that many web pages are in the [deep web](https://youtu.be/joxQ_XbsPVw), for example by them being listed in the robots.txt file on a website server—these pages are not indexed. Other pages in the deep web include those where log-in access is required, such as a "friends-only" Facebook post. A public Facebook or Twitter post is in the surface-level web.

In most cases, Google Drive links are not put on web pages, so that is why most public Google Drive files are not indexed.

Comment: If a google document is linked from a public website, I understand it could be indexed. How would this impact SEO from the site it is linked from?

Comment: SEO on the website is primarily dependent on the words, phrases and language on the site, the length of time that visitors spend on the site, and how often the site is linked from elsewhere on the internet (e.g. from social media posts which aren't adverts). So, I think that outgoing links from the site won't contribute to SEO. Especially as it decreases the length of time that visitors stay on the site, although it could make the site more relevant as a reference point, increasing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Google can index Google docs in its search results but the same criteria apply as for all web content, so if its overly short or clearly nonsense then it probably won't get picked up.   I tried an experiment a few months ago with Google docs and Google Drive files, even long and useful pages which 100% will be indexed if they were web pages were not picked up, even when I included links to them on high authority sites.  Hope your studies went well in the end.